# Javascript if string contains part of another string

Tags: javascript

Not sure the best way to explain it but I need to have javascript search one string to see if part of that string matches another. With the below code var e lists some state abbreviations. I then tried several different if statements. The first statement I tried the search statement instead of "indexof". that does not work. The second if statement works only because there is one value in the variable. The third statement does not work because once again there are multiple values in the varable.

I need the statement to run if the state abbreviation appears in both strings.

```
var e = "MT, MI, OH, DC, ";
var TFF = "MT, WY, ND, SD, NE, MN, IA, WI, KS, MO, OK, AR, LA, TX, ";
if (e.search(TFF) === -1) {
  document.getElementById("test1").style.display = "block";
} else {}
if (e.indexOf("MI") >= 0) {
  document.getElementById("test2").style.display = "block";
} else {}
if (e.indexOf("DC DE MD PA VA WV") >= 0) {
  document.getElementById("test3").style.display = "block";
} else {}
```

Comment: Problem is your code needs to match exactly. So what you have to do is break it up into an array and check for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The esiest way to compare them is to convert both into an array Then check one array against another run a for loop in loop

```js
var e = "MT, MI, OH, DC, ";
var TFF = "MT, WY, ND, SD, NE, MN, IA, WI, KS, MO, OK, AR, LA, TX, ";

var arraye = e.split(",");
var arrayTiff = TFF.split(",");

for(values in arraye){

  //console.log(arraye[values])

 for (value2 in arrayTiff)

  {
    if(arraye[values]==arrayTiff[value2])
    console.log(arraye[values])
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add code in there that doesn't include empty strings

Comment: I added all my needed if statements within the for(values in arraye){ and it woked perfect. I know very little about javascript but was able to get this to work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

First break the strings into arrays and strip out the whitespace for each element. Then use a `filter()` function to filter out non-matching values:

```js
const e = "MT, MI, OH, DC, ";
const TFF = "MT, WY, ND, SD, NE, MN, IA, WI, KS, MO, OK, AR, LA, TX, ";

let arr1 = e.split(",");
let arr2 = TFF.split(",");

arr1 = arr1.map(val => val.trim()).filter(val => val !== "");
arr2 = arr2.map(val => val.trim()).filter(val => val !== "");

const res = arr2.filter(val => arr1.includes(val)); 
console.log(res);
```

**Update:**

With regular expressions:

```js
const e = "MT, MI, OH, DC, ";
const TFF = "MT, WY, ND, SD, NE, MN, IA, WI, KS, MO, OK, AR, LA, TX, ";

const re = /[A-Z]{2}/g;
const res = TFF.match(re).filter(val => e.match(re).includes(val));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the strings to arrays (either by hand or using `String#split`).

Examples:

```js
var TFF = "MT, WY, ND, SD, NE, MN, IA, WI, KS, MO, OK, AR, LA, TX, ";

var temp = TFF.split(/,\s+/);
console.log(temp.filter(Boolean));
// or
temp.pop();
console.log(temp);
// or
console.log(JSON.parse("[\"" + TFF.replace(/,\s+/g, "\",\"").replace(/,"$/, "") + "]"));
```

Then check if any of the strings is contained in the other array.

Example:

```js
var e = ["MT", "MI", "OH", "DC"];
var tff = ["MT", "WY", "ND", "SD", "NE", "MN", "IA", "WI", "KS", "MO", "OK", "AR", "LA", "TX"];
var other = ["DC", "DE", "MD", "PA", "VA", " WV"];

if (e.some(x => tff.includes(x))) console.log("Test 1");
// or
if (tff.some(x => e.includes(x))) console.log("Test 1");

if (e.some(x => x === "MI")) console.log("Test 2");
// or
if (e.includes("MI")) console.log("Test 2");

if (e.some(x => other.includes(x))) console.log("Test 3");
// or
if (other.some(x => e.includes(x))) console.log("Test 3");
```

Comment: I get an error stating the "arrow function syntax is only available in ES6" I tried adding the version at the top but that still does not work

/*jshint esversion: 6 */
var e = "MI, MT, ";
var twofourfive = ["MT", "WY", "ND", "SD", "NE", "MN", "IA", "WI", "KS", "MO", "OK", "AR", "LA", "TX"];

if (e.some(x => twofourfive.includes(x))) console.log("Test 1");
// or
if (twofourfive.some(x => e.includes(x))) console.log("Test 1");

if (e.some(x => x === "MI")) console.log("Test 2");
// or
if (e.includes("MI")) console.log("Test 2");

Comment: You need to add the `"esversion": 6` property in your `.jshintrc` file. You could also just replace the arrow functions with normal functions (I only used to make the example shorter and clearer). `x => tff.includes(x)` can be replaced by `function(x){return tff.includes(x);}`

Answer (score -1):

```js
const eArr = e.split(“,”).sort();
const fttArr = ftt.stplit(“,”).sort();
let found =0;
for (let i =0; i <= eArr.lengt; ++I) { 
  if (eArr[i] === fttArr[i]) ++found;
}

found === eArr.length
```